# I can't change output of CONSTRUCT Query - concat doesn't work as expected

Tags: sparql, ontology, sparql-generate

I use Protege v5.5.0 to create a query from RDF/XML file with the content:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:some="http://some.org/#"
         xml:base="http://some.org/">

<some:builder rdf:about="#Builder1">
<some:built rdf:resource="#Building1"/>
<some:built rdf:resource="#Building2"/>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="#building"/>
</some:builder>


<some:builder rdf:about="#Builder2">
<some:built rdf:resource="#Building3"/>
</some:builder >

</rdf:RDF>
```

I am using a CONSTRUCT query like this:

```
PREFIX art: <http://some.org/#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT   {?y some:wasBuiltBy ?x
}
WHERE       { ?x some:built ?y
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
building1   some:wasBuiltBy     Builder1 
building2   some:wasBuiltBy     Builder2 
building3   some:wasBuiltBy     Builder3
```

But expected output must be like this:

```
 some:building1   some:wasBuiltBy     some:Builder1 
 some:building2   some:wasBuiltBy     some:Builder2 
 some:building3   some:wasBuiltBy     some:Builder3
```

The task is to add to the outputted subjects and objects the prefix "some:".
I tried to use CONCAT:

```
PREFIX art: <http://some.org/#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT   {(CONCAT("some:", ?y) as ?y) some:wasBuiltBy (CONCAT("some:", ?x) as ?x)
}
WHERE       { ?x some:built ?y
}
```

but it returned an error.
I would welcome any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your query:

1- You need to bind the variables in the `WHERE` clause and not in the `CONSTRUCT`.
So, you'll need:

```
PREFIX art: <http://some.org/#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT { ?newY some:wasBuiltBy ?newX }
WHERE {
?x some:built ?y .
BIND(CONCAT("some:", ?y) AS ?newY)
BIND(CONCAT("some:", ?x) as ?newX)
}
```

2- Prefixes are for IRIs, not strings. So you'll need to account for this, as below:

```
PREFIX art: <http://some.org/#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT { ?newY some:wasBuiltBy ?newX }
WHERE {
?x some:built ?y .
BIND(IRI(CONCAT(STR(some:), STR(?y))) AS ?newY)
BIND(IRI(CONCAT(STR(some:), STR(?x)) as ?newX)
}
```

This will ensure first that `?x` and `?y` are actually strings, which they may not be.

Then, you will concatenate the prefix `some:`, i.e. `"http://some.prefix/etc#"`, rather than the string `"some:"`.

Finally, you will convert the whole concatenation to an IRI.

Comment: Thank you for you help @ValerioCocchi. I followed your instructions, but something went wrong. I had a message about the error in protege: Caused by: org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException: Unknown function 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#concat'  Probably could you advise how to fix it, please? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like `CONCAT` is not supported... What triplestore are you using?

Comment: it's not a triple store, it's Protege which makes use of an older version of RDF4J -

Comment: @ValerioCocchi I use local file with RDF/XML, I added information about its structure to my initial question.

Comment: @UninformedUser Could you advise how to overcome the issue, please?